# How to Create Multiple Model Objects in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model called coupon with a foreign realation to Course model. I need to create multiple coupons with coupon model. Let's say if the count is 50 then it should save 50 coupons in the database. Can I achieve that using bulk_create() method and how to do that. Also I'm using Django Rest Framework

```
class Coupon(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="expire_date", default=now())
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can make use of [**`.bulk_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create), although you first should fix the `default=…` parameter for the `expre_date`. If you set this as `default=now()` it will take as `expire_date` the time when the *class* was interpreted, so that is very close to when you started the server. You probably want to set this to the datetime when the `coupon` was created:

```
class Coupon(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='expire_date', default=now)
```

You can create a number of records for a given `Course` with a given expire date with:

```
from datetime import datetime

course = None  # … ← the course for which the coupons are used
expire_date = datetime(2021, 11, 7)  # ← when will the coupons expire
n = 50  # ← number of coupons to create

Coupon.objects.bulk_create(
    [
        Coupon(course=course, expire_date=expire_date)
        for __ in range(n)
    ]
)
```

We thus will make one query to the database to insert all 50 coupons.